# Что быстрее? cin>>buff или read(0,buff,size)

Tags: c++, linux, c, файловая-система

Сказано, что `read` это системный вызов, и его преимущество перед функциями из других библиотек, в том, что по определению системный вызов должен быстро завершиться. Конечно `read()` сравнивать с `cin` можно только завернув `read()` в цикл `while', но даже так, мне кажется read() должен быть побыстрее. Так ли это?

Comment: cin в любом случае просто обертка поверх того же read. А дополнительный уровень косвенности конечно медленнее, чем прямое использование. хотя еще от оптимизатора зависит, может он умудриться инлайн подстановку при работе с cin использовать

Comment: . Как получить время выполнения программы?.. Ответы найдете и здесь и в гугле.  Вот и проверьте сами... По моему в разных ситуациях получите разный результат.

Comment: Исходя из моего опыта, методы чтения и записи C++ чуть медленнее. Поэтому на некоторых контестах, если приходится очень много читать и/или писать, то как правильно используются функции из C, иначе получаешь time limit. Но чем дальше, тем проверяющие системы оснащаются более производительными машинами и разница становится практически незаметной.

Comment: А Вы напишите тестовую программу, сделайте в цикле 100500 чтений read а потом 100500 чтений cin, засеките время по системным часам и сравните. Только читайте из файла а не с консоли, а то надоест ввод нажимать. :-)

Comment: А у вас точно-точно вывод - это самое то место, которое тормозит всю программу?

Comment: Мне кажется, что устройства ввода-вывода сами по себе вносят _такие_ тормоза в процесс чтения данных, что надо очень сильно стараться, чтобы его сколько-нибудь заметно затормозить или ускорить программно.